# How to custom ember data's restful URL and modify the HTTP method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I use ember data in my project. I know the REST adapter's URL conventions are as follows:

```
Action  | HTTP Verb| URL
------- | ---------|---------
Find    | GET      | /posts/1
Find All| GET      | /posts
Update  | PUT      | /posts/1
Create  | POST     | /posts
Delete  | DELETE   | /posts/1
```

But I got a backend's URL like this

```
Action  | HTTP Verb| URL
------- | ---------|---------
Find    | GET      | /posts/show/1
Find All| GET      | /posts/list
Update  | POST     | /posts/update/1
Create  | POST     | /posts/add
Delete  | POST     | /posts/delete/1
```

The URL and HTTP verb are both different. I know that I can customize the URL with `buildURL (modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query)`.I think I can check the requestType and hardcode the URL. I would like to know if there is a elegant way to customize the URL and modify the HTTP method? Thank you.

`Ember version 1.12.0
Ember-Cli version 0.2.5
Ember Data version 1.0.0-beta.17`

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with override the following method in application adapter.

`` * `find()`
* `createRecord()`
* `updateRecord()`
* `deleteRecord()`
* `findAll()`
* `findQuery()` ``

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/greyby/c6ad2dd5f4592867d43d)

Comment: I believe you made a correct choice - to implement it by yourself. Right now there is an on-going discussion about resource path management in ember-data like [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-urls-for-ember-datas-restadapter-proposal)